# java with opencv program not running in command prompt,package org.opencv.core does not exist

Tags: java, opencv

I have to make a java program using the OpenCV library in Netbeans, which is working fine. I want to make.exe of that program so I made the jar file but that jar file is not opening then I compile that program in the command prompt the error is package org.opencv.core does not exist. so plz provides the solution how I compile the java program which contains OpenCV library and makes .exe file and jar file??

[image]

Comment: Can you show your sourcecode and your pom.xml? or other build conf file?

Comment: put opencv jar in your classpath before building exe

Comment: Sanjeev I had add opencv jar in  Netbeans ide in project property using this -Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64"